# ASP.NET Error Message System.Web.UI.Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why am getting this error message in my default.aspx.cs in the page_load?

*Error  1   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   F:\ASP.NET\Exercises\XEx02Quotation\Default.aspx.cs 16  30  XEx02Quotation*

I am doing a simple price quote calculator.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
    if (!IsPostBack)
        for (int i = 50; i <= 500; i += 50)
        {
            txtSalePrice.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
}

protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        decimal salePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscountPercent.Text);
        decimal discountPercent  = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscountPercent.Text);
        decimal discountAmount = Convert.ToInt32(lblDiscountAmount.Text);

        decimal dAmount = salePrice-(salePrice*discountPercent);
        lblDiscountAmount.Text= discountAmount.ToString("c");

        lblTotalPrice.Text = (salePrice - discountAmount).ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: The control txtSalePrice is being accessed as a ComboBox, however, it is defined as a textbox.

Comment: The teacher is requesting the user's input to be a text box. Is there an alternative than .Items.Add?

Comment: You can have a text box as well as a drop down list in your aspx page. The user could provide input in the text box, and the drop down list could contain all possible items in your scenario.

Comment: @GrantWinney The user is asked to input the sale price, then prompted to put in the discount percentage. The output is giving the user the discount amount and the total price after the discount.  His instruction doesn't go into detail on holding the values the user is inputting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtSalesPrice` is a `TextBox` type (`System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`). You can't add `Items` to a `TextBox`. Try using a `ListBox` instead.

Or use a multiline TextBox and change the following line from

```
txtSalePrice.Items.Add(i.ToString());
```

to

```
txtSalePrice.Text = "\n" + i.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it work. Can you tell me why did this work?

Comment: Yes, as I explaine you cannot add Items to a textBox control, which is not supported. But, you could do this with a ListBox control. Otherwise you could just append to Text property of a TextBox with NewLine character (\n). You must enable MultiLine property of your text box to have multiple lines.

Comment: yes this did fix the problem. It would not let me vote.

Comment: No worries then. Happy to help! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`txtSalePrice` is a TextBox. It has not the property named `Items`. You should use a ListBox or DropDownList in this case.